# Installing Applications on Mac through Network

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, applications, automator

I need to install an application to number of Macs. Is there any way i can do it over the network or any other advise on this.

Thanks

Comment: How is the application provided? Is it just an .app package which needs to be copied to /Applications or does an installer need to be run on each target system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. I use Apple's "Remote Desktop" application which allows you to both copy files and install packages (in addition to other management tasks) to multiple computers.

Here is Apple's page on the software:
http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/

The management software you pay for runs on one Mac. The client is already part of the Mac OS and you just have to turn it on -- System Preferences -> Sharing then check "Remote Management". You can allow access from any user or specified users. I normally limit access to the local admin user on the computer. In the Remote Desktop application you add the computer to a list of managed computers and in that process you authenticate as the user under which you will be administering the computer. If you have a lot of computers to manage, you can create lists of computers in addition to the big list of all computers.

Comment: Thanks. Do i have to buy it for one or multiple macs?

Comment: @huseinasj you only need it on the administrative Mac. All other Macs need the ARD Client, which is installed by default with OS X